# Google Search app results on desktop

Tags: google-search

My question is simple - I like reading the results of the Google Search app - it's become much better at allowing me to customise these results, as well as becoming better at predicting what I might like.

Does anyone know if there is a way I can view the results of the Google Search app on my Windows desktop machine, either by installing a desktop application or by navigating to a website that shows these results?

Comment: Check [this](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/54068?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). I can't verify because I keep it turned off

Comment: @beeshyams, this is a bit different from what I'm asking for. The content at the link talks about how to change your search preferences, but what I want is to able to see the same search results that I see in the Google search app.

Comment: What I meant was to see in your search history if that can help you